# How can I "upload and deploy" to Elastic Beanstalk from the command line?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

To start, apologies if this is a foolish question -- I'm relatively new to AWS and none of my googling has been fruitful thus far.

I have a server that I deploy through elastic beanstalk. Currently I do it relatively manually (docker build, push, zip folder and click `upload and deploy` and the elastic beanstalk page with the zip I just made.

I'm writing a script to simplify this. Everything seems to be working, but I can't figure out how to do the `upload and deploy` step programmatically. Just to be very explicit, this is the button I'm referring to:
[image]

Is there a way I can do this bit using python? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the EB CLI to deploy and manage your Application

> [Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface (EB CLI)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html)